# Why does this not make a difference between property and variable?

Tags: php

```
class someclass
{
    public $foo = 'abcd';

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->foo = $data;
    }
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        echo $foo = $_POST['foo']; // This output correct value     
        var_dump($foo); // This Output NULL
        $somethingelse = $_POST['foo'];
        var_dump($somethingelse); // Output as expected

    }
}
```

If i change my variable name or property name from `$foo` to something else in do in `doSomething()` it runs fine.

Why do I need to keep the property name and variable name different here?

Why does `$foo` is `NULL` when one of the property name is `$foo`?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running, as this is working fine for me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$this->foo` to get and set the classes property

Comment: Read question carefully again

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
echo $foo = $_POST['foo'];
```

to

```
echo $this->foo = $_POST['foo'];
var_dump($this->foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

When accessing class variables you need to use the `$this->` prefix.

Change your code to

```
echo $this->foo = $_POST['foo'];
var_dump($this->foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correct and it works fine. I ran your code and it always gives me the same. There's no problem you have property $foo and $foo variable in one or multiple functions. It always give me the same answer.

If $_POST['foo']=test then echo $foo = $_POST['foo']; returns "test", $foo returns "test" and $somethingelse returns "test";